# Write MP3 in Python

Tags: python, file, mp3

I have a bunch of frames (generated by a function) that I want to write to a MP3 file using Python. I tried using `pymedia` but I always get a Segmentation fault.

Doe anyone know an extension to write MP3 files using Python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Gnome, [soundconverter](http://soundconverter.org/) might help; but I don't know of a stand-alone equivalent.

Comment: I don't need an application, I need a Python extension

Comment: @Yassin, `soundconverter`'s source code (being in Python;-) of course contains and uses the "Python extension" which accesses Gnome's libraries used to read and write various kinds of sound files, including MP3. But you do get a dependency on Gnome, as I mentioned.